# Why are touches not detected at top of screen with status bar hidden?

Tags: ios, uikit

In our app, we show modal windows that take up the whole screen, and we hide the status bar at this time. However, buttons placed at the top of the screen have reduced hit areas: their tops do not detect touches. This is true of custom buttons and buttons in the navigation controller.

What is preventing detection of those touches?

FYI: I have two other windows, a HUD view and a status bar overlay, and both are hidden. I've tried putting the status bar overlay behind the main window, as well. Problem remains.

Update: This problem is caused, at least in some cases, by hiding the status bar while still having a scroll view with scrollsToTop set to YES. Although I have found a case where the problem remains even after disabling scrollsToTop for all resident scroll views. (I wrote a simple method to walk the view hierarchy to find all scroll views and report their current scrollsToTop setting.)

Comment: try setting StatusBar Translucent.

Comment: have you found any solution to this yourself?

Comment: Follow up. I forgot about this question. If memory serves, the problem was that multiple scroll views were present on-screen which had "scrollsToTop" enabled, which isn't supported.